# Show input-text into the text-area

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show text in a text-area using multiple text-fields. [Check out this link](http://www.vistaprint.co.uk/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?pf_id=088&combo_id=160113&combo=430116.142.1.195042%7C195042%7C137%7C0&uei=159600&ag=true&ssc=1&filter=9:10013%7C%7C1,4:10003%7C%7C1,3:10001%7C%7C1&xnav=previews&xnid=image_1&rd=2&ref=1&referer=http://www.vistaprint.co.uk/gallery.aspx?pg=1&xnav=HowToDesign&GP=7/13/2013%204:13:53%20AM&GPS=2895675993&GNF=1); on the left side there are many input fields, and this input value shows up in the text-area. I am trying to use the `keyup` event.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $('#name').keyup(function () {$('#fname').text($(this).val());'</br>'});
</script>

<script>
    $('#field').keyup(function () {$('.sname').text($(this).val());});
</script>
```

That function works fine, but when write second name in text-field it overwrites the first input.[Check full my code live](http://musicjee.com/New%20directory/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

Instead of using `key-up` event use blur so that when second text box looses focus you get desirable results:

Declare a global variable `txt` and then assign value to it on first text-box blur event while append to it the value of second text-box on blur (focus lost) event.

The reason why `key-up` won't work for you is, eventually you will need to append the text from two text-boxes and while first text-box will work perfectly fine but the key-up for second text-box will continuously append text on every key-up with a newline character.

Something like this would work for you if key-up event is not the topmost priority for you:

```
var txt ='';

$('#name').blur(function () {
    if ($('#field').val().length > 0){
        txt = $(this).val() + '\n' + $('#field').val();
    } else {
        txt = $('#name').val();
    }   
  $('#fname').text(txt);  
});
$('#field').blur(function () {
    txt = '';
    txt = $('#name').val() + '\n' + $(this).val();
  $('.sname').text(txt);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xHyY/

### Update

It now is more synchronized. Basically one second text-box blur clear the txt variable and assign the values again. Checking also included for first text-box blur.
Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xHyY/4/

If you still want this whole process to be based on key-up/down event. You will have to use multiple `DIVs` instead of single `TextArea`

Comment: Actually, I would use blur for both text-boxes to be consistent.

Comment: First field work fine but when second function pass value again and again .i mean go to the next line when you focus out and write again.

Comment: I see, you are talking about a situation where you focus out and then focus in and so on. Right?

Comment: Yes. Basically second function are not controlled.they run again and again so that's why when focus-out they go to the next line.

Comment: Thanks but now i want add more input-field which function use again for more input-fields.

Comment: I would say you will have to write a small plugin or function for that. But the main logic remains same as above. Or if you have really limited time and less than 10 input fields do it statically one by one.

Comment: Ok fine.Now i am try implement CKeditor plugin can you have idea how to add this function into the plugin.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about CKeditor.But shouldn't be different. Depends on how to write text to it.